# How reset combobox value with change event ExtJS

Tags: php, extjs

I need help regarding resetting the `combobox`, I have tried using the following code:

```
change: function (this, newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(NewValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:-

```
change: function (combo, newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(NewValue);
    combo.suspendEvents();
    combo.reset();
    combo.resumeEvents();
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i change event with keydown and it works